# Posting Compressed JSON to Laravel API Endpoint

Tags: php, .net, laravel, compression

I did some basic tests using Apache Benchmark and it looks like posting 500 records from C# using the `DeflateStream` class to PHP results in about a 3X increase in processing speed, and reduced bandwidth from 140k to 10k with only an extra 2% CPU increase per post.

I am trying to now update my existing API endpoints so that if old connectors still send uncompressed data it won't break, but updated connectors sending compressed data would be auto decompressed. While I have a proof of concept in plain PHP, with Laravel but am not sure how to work it into the mix with the `Request` class. Here is how my API starts:

```
public function BasicApi(Request $request)
{
    $messages = [
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'data' => 'required|array',
    ], $messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new UpdateResourceFailedException('Could not sync.', $validator->errors());
    }

    $reference_id = collect($request->input('data'))->pluck('reference_id');
    ........  more stuff  ........

}
```

With straight PHP I was able to work up a way to filter whether the incoming code was compressed or not:

```
$incomingData = gzinflate(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
if (file_get_contents('php://input') != $incomingData && $incomingData !== FALSE) {
     $incomingData = gzinflate(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}
echo $source;
```

What should I do to be able to send my Laravel API compressed data? If I let Apache uncompress it automatically then the request all gets over escaped like this:

```
&quot;{\&quot;data\&quot;:[{\&quot;reference_id\&quot;:\&quot;75080\&quot;...
```

If I don't let it do it automatically then I am not sure how to inject the incoming into the `Request` object.